# Hover state on an element when mouse is over its container DIV

Tags: css, hover

I'd need to recreate the following effect: *hovering onto `.card container`, should trigger `:hover` also on `.btn` inside it*.

Please, consider this example code: https://codepen.io/ldetomi/pen/ZEoNprQ

Ok, could be possible to use JS and trigger an '`hover`' css class onto inner .btn, but this will force me to duplicate code for hover state of .btn, for `:hover` pseudo-state and `.hover` class. Or, in another way, I'd need to duplicate state of hover buttons, in case that is *child* of a DIV that has an 'hover' state.

Due to the thing that i have a complex style for hover state of buttons, I'd like to be able to trigger the same hover effect on it, also if hover is made onto *father* DIV in a smart way.

If, possible, I'd like to avoid something like this:

```
.btn {
  &:hover {
    background: red;
  }
}

.card {
  &:hover {
    .btn {
      background: red;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add the below rule.

.card:hover > .btn {
background: red;
}

Edit :

You can club both hover rules together to prevent code duplication

```
.card:hover > .btn, .btn:hover 
{ 
background:red;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I knew this kind of things (as I wrote '_I'd need to duplicate state of hover buttons, in case that is child of a DIV that has an 'hover' state_'). 
This is a possibile solution, but I'd like, if possible, to avoid code duplication

Comment: you can put them both in a single rule then

i.e. 

.card:hover > .btn, .btn:hover { background:red;}, this way your same hover rule applies to both conditions, so no code duplication.